# Not able to re-enable CheckBoxGroup items through setItemEnabledProvider()

Tags: vaadin, disable

I am using a CheckBoxGroup in Vaadin, When a condition is true I want few of the items need to be disabled, but I am able to disable only one item how to disable multiple items(not all items). Also when that condition is false I want the disabled items to be re-enabled. cbGroupUpdated is the checkboxgroup with Orange, Grape, Apple, Beans,Carrot as items.

cbGroupUpdated.addValueChangeListener(e - >

```
{
    if (cbGroupUpdated.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Orange")) {
        cbGroupUpdated.setItemEnabledProvider(item - > item.equalsIgnoreCase("Orange"));
    } else {
        cbGroupUpdated.setItemEnabledProvider(item - > item.equalsIgnoreCase("Carrot"));
        cbGroupUpdated.setItemEnabledProvider(item - > item.equalsIgnoreCase("Beans"));
    }
});
```

Result: When I select the Orange checkbox, all items(Grape, Apple, Beans,Carrot) except Orange are disabled( but I want only the carrot and beans to be disabled.), When I Uncheck the Orange checkbox I want the Carrot and Beans checkboxes to be re-enabled but it is not happening and the checkboxes remains disabled. Please correct my mistakes and provide better solution.

Comment: You can only add / set ONE Item enabled provider. Combine the different provider's validations with a logical OR operator.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how the enabled provider (actually more a predicate) works.
If the method is named `set` in Vaadin, that means, that you have 0 or
1; calling set multiple times *replaces* the previous predicate.  If you
have witnessed, that this tactic works somewhere else, it's an
implementation detail you should not rely on.

So only call *set* one provider for your "not-orange" case and rewrite
it can deal with all cases (e.g. use "or" or create a `Set` for all the
cases and check for containment).